# Submit a file element with jquery and ajax: No plugins wanted!

Tags: forms, jquery, form-submit

I'm trying to do a submit via ajax of a form that contains a file element.

```
<form id="classic_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
 <br/>
<!-- ...other inputs...-->
<button type="button" id="classic_save"> Send </button> 
</form>
```

What I need to do is to submit this form and check if the file fulfills some requirements, so I wrote an ajax submit for this form

```
         $('#classic_save').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:'<g:createLink action="classicUploadFile" controller="scan"/>',
              
              success: function(msg){
                        alert("Data Loaded: " + msg);                
              }
            });
          });
```

However, I have no idea how to send the file through ajax.

## Some context

Originally we were using swfUpload for this. However, we ran into some trouble  with https and some certificate issues. So we decided to implement a basic html fallback. Plugins are nice, but we need to guarantee that this fall back is bullet proof (thinking of google mail "classic upload").

Any thoughts? Are ***iframes*** the way to go (read somewhere google mail uses them for their classic upload)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, there is [jQuery Uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/) to do exactly what you are looking for other than other great features.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [jQuery AJAX form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) on my site to [upload files](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find a really good example/tutorial how to upload one file http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

Hope it works for you.
Cheers